# Unable to print tf.zeros in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, eval

```
weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([image_size * image_size, num_labels]))
biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_labels]))`
```

This is a part of the code I encountered to minimize loss using Gradient Descent in tensorflow.
I understood what is going on and what **tf.zeros** is doing but when I tried to run the follwing code it showed an error::

```
 sess = tf.IntearctiveSession()
 tensor = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=(10)))
 print(tensor.eval())
 sess.close()
```

An error occured in `print(tensor.eval())`.
Can someone point out where I understood the things wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to [initialize your variable(s)](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables#initializing_variables). Try this:

```
sess = tf.IntearctiveSession()
tensor = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=(10)))
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())  # Now all variables are initialized
print(tensor.eval())
sess.close()
```

Comment: thanks, @landogardner sorry for such a silly question as my concepts are not clear

Comment: No need to be sorry :-) And I don't think it's that silly a question: for example, if you'd used `tf.constant` in your original code instead of `tf.Variable`, there would have been no error (but of course you want to use `tf.Variable` for what you're doing...)